# Bind spring form to a list element

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

Is it possible to bind spring `form:form` to a list element? I've tried this way.

```
<form:form commandName="products[0]">
   <form:input path="name"/>
</form:form>
```

also

```
<form:form commandName="products0">
   <form:input path="name"/>
</form:form>
```

Where `products` list is populated in spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAll(Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("products", productService.getAll());
    return "products";
}
```

Received: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'products[0]' available as request attribute`. Which as I understand means that spring haven't found where to bind the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The value you pass to the `commandName` attribute is a key and it is not resolved like a normal EL or SpEL expression would be. It is used directly. In other words, with

```
<form:form commandName="products[0]">
   <form:input path="name"/>
</form:form>
```

Spring will look for a model attribute called `products[0]` which it won't find.

The alternative is to put the first element of the list in the model directly with a key you will use in your jsp.

Or you can use JSTL, get the first element in the list and create an HTML `<form>` element yourself.